# Invisible unicode character (0x200E) is showing a marker in Android TextView (Gingerbread and below)

Tags: android

I am inserting [\u200E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) marks in English strings to force left to right. This invisible unicode character (BiDi mark) works fine on ICS and Jelly Bean, but I am noticing a weird marker when running the code on Gingerbread as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code I used to reproduce this issue:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView view = new TextView(this);
        view.setText("text \u200E\u200E\u200E text");
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this invisible character is shown and how to hide it?

Comment: did adding this mark help you force the alignment on pre-ICS versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that character is not supported by the System's font of Gingerbread. You can use a *custom font* on your View, e.g. the Roboto font, which is used by Android 4.0 and higher.

Roboto can be downloaded from here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html